# How can I set parameters with a Click-Once package?

Tags: clickonce

I am developing a WinForms app which will be used at a company with many physical locations across the country.

This app will open files (such as PowerPoint) which will be placed on the local server at each plant by a separate sync process.

My challenge is to create a click-once installer that can be run at any facility, but once installed it will know where to look for the local files.  There is a central SQL server so all the installations will have a common connection string, and they can each query the database for a record with the local server path, but I can't think of a way that when the program starts it knows what facility it is at.

The only option that I can think of is to create a separate click-once installer for each plant that would contain info that would allow it to know where it is being used.  This is obviously very problematic since I would have to create and maintain several installers, and hope that users would select the proper one when needed.

Does anyone have a good idea for this ?

Thanks !

Comment: You could add a parameter to the `app.config` file and modify it for each facility. Please note: You need to resign the application then.

Comment: OK, thanks for the tip.  Resigning would be a little bit of a hassle, but possible.  Also, I thought that the app.config was included in the clickonce and therefore would not be available for edit.  I would prefer to have a single clickonce that anyone in the organization could use, but that may not be possible.

Comment: Oh, I think you didn't understand how ClickOnce works. You don't get one setup file from it. It will create an application manifest and put all the `*.exe` and `*.dll` in a subfolder. Also a bootstraper (setup.exe) is generated. If you want a single setup file, you have to use another setup technology.

Comment: Yes, I see now what you are saying. I appreciate your help, how do I give you credit ?  I don't see a way to do so  (I'm new at this).

Comment: By accepting the answer. Feel free to add another comment down on it, if something is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments on your question, you could add a parameter to the `app.config` file and modify it for each facility. But as already said, you would need to resign the application for each facility then.

As you want to have a single setup file, using ClickOnce is a really bad idea here. >ou don't get one setup file ,rather than a created application manifest and all the *.exe and *.dll files in a subfolder. Also a bootstraper (setup.exe) is generated. If you want a single setup file, you have to use another setup technology.

For example, there's a [list on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software) of available installer technologies.
You might have to search a little bit for a installer tech that suites your needs.
But most professional softwares should offer such a capability.